# how to get time stamp for the example: 2016-08-29T09:15:17Z?

Tags: java, datetime

I have tried to get the date format `2016-08-29T09:15:17Z` but not able to get the trailing `Z` at the end.

I also checked the date time documentation at official website but could not find a similar pattern. So far the date format I have created is as follows:

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

So far the code I have written is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException{
        Date nDate=new Date();
        //SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMYYYYHHMMSS");
        String date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(nDate);
        System.out.println(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The T is just a literal to separate the date from the time, and the Z means "zero hour offset" also known as "Zulu time" (UTC). If your strings always have a "Z" you can use -

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"); // optional
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"); // Quoted "Z" to indicate UTC, no timezone offset
dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone); // optional
String date = dateFormat .format(new Date()); // date will have the required format
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: `Try this` is not an answer. explain why it sould work.

Answer (score 0):

`Z` is a constant value like `T` in your string, so you have to put single quotes arround it:

```
String date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").format(nDate);
```

If you use `Z` without single quotes DateFormat expect the timezone value

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Documentation describe that `z` and `Z` both are use for time zone.
So if you don't want special meaning of `Z` then you need to write like :

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding another way to do it, using the new java.time API introduced from JDK 8 onwards.

```
      LocalDateTime nDate=LocalDateTime.now();
      DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
              .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
              .appendLiteral('T')
              .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
              .appendLiteral('Z')                              
              .toFormatter();
       String date = formatter.format(nDate);
       System.out.println(date);
```